# Using MAX() to get all the latest dates from a query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with a query, I am trying to filter out all duplicate rows by using max(DATE).

My query is the following -

```
 $sql = "select COND_CODE,COUNT(*) as COUNT, COND_CODE, MAX(DATE) from downgrades
 WHERE (
    SELECT MAX(DATE) BETWEEN '15/05/2014 05:19' AND '30/05/2014 12:34' from downgrades)
    GROUP BY COND_CODE";
```

The query is pulling data, but the only result it actually gives is the very last date in the table.

```
COND_CODE      DATE     
SW             21/05/2014 07:57
SW             21/05/2014 07:59
SW             22/05/2014 09:05
SW             22/05/2014 09:06
SM             27/05/2014 06:49
SM             27/05/2014 06:49
SM             30/05/2014 05:18
```

The query above would only give one result - SM  30/05/2014 05:18.

I need it to show the latest result for each COND_CODE by filtering the latest date.

So ideally I would get  SM  30/05/2014 05:18   &   SW  22/05/2014 09:06

Hope this makes sense,

Thanks

Comment: This is MySQL. Those aren't dates...

Comment: How aren't they dates? They are converted from a julian time stamp....

Comment: Dates in SQL should be transcribed to the DATE or DATETIME data types - YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s

Comment: I dont want it in that format. What has this got to do with the question I asked?

Comment: If you don't want to store it in that format, don't use SQL. What happens if you insert a row for 12th June, say?

Comment: I Don't want to insert a row.

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` to filter out duplicates.

Comment: Can't use distinct as there is more data to the table than just them two columns. thats why I have to use date to filter them out.

Comment: You cannot MAX a string reliably.

Comment: So isn't there a way to what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```
SELECT COND_CODE,COUNT(*) as COUNT, COND_CODE, MAX(DATE) 
FROM downgrades
GROUP BY COND_CODE
HAVING MAX(DATE) BETWEEN '15/05/2014 05:19' AND '30/05/2014 12:34'
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but I got the same results that I'm already getting.

Comment: This should work better: SELECT Code, MAX(Date) 
FROM `downgrades` 
GROUP BY Code
HAVING MAX(Date) BETWEEN '2014-05-15 05:19' AND '2014-05-30 12:34'. Assuming that your 'DATE' field is actually of mysql type 'datetime'. I tested this myself and results as you specified.